How to prove the continuity of the path lifting function of covering spaces.
Let $p\colon E \to B$ be a covering map. The path lifting function $\varphi\colon E \times_p B^I \to E^I$, where $E \times_p B^I := \{(e, \gamma) \in E \times B^I : \gamma(0) = p(e)\}$ is a pullback of $E$ and $B^I$, is the function that lifts a path $\gamma$ in $B$ to a path in $E$ which starts from a specific point $e \in E$. $E^I$ and $B^I$ are equipped with the compact-open topology. I want to show that $\varphi$ is continuous, hence a homeomorphism which further indicates that covering maps are Hurewicz fibrations.
I've come up with a complicated proof by myself, but I believe that there should be a more concise and elegant one.
If $p : E \to B$ is a covering map, then the path lifting function $\varphi : E \times_p B^I \to E^I$ is continuous.

Take $V := \bigcap S(K_i, U_i) \subseteq E^I$. $S(I, U)$ where $U := \bigcap U_i$ is open in $V$.
We need to show that $\varphi^{-1}(S(I, U)) \subseteq B^I$ is open.
Let $(e, \gamma) \in \varphi^{-1}(S(I, U))$, this means the lift $\tilde{\gamma} = \varphi(e, \gamma)$ satiesfies $\tilde{\gamma}(I) \subseteq U$
Since $p : E \to B$ is a covering map, for every $t \in I$, there is a $C \in B[\gamma(t)]$ that $p^{-1}(C) = \bigsqcup_{f \in F} D_f$, $p \upharpoonright D_f$ is homeomorphic.$\tilde{\gamma}(t) \in p^{-1}(C)$. Therefore, $\tilde{\gamma}(t) \in D_f$ for some $f \in F$. $V_t := D_f \cap U$, $W_t := C \cap p(U)$. $V_t \in U[\tilde{\gamma}(t)]$ and $W_t \in B[\gamma(t)]$. $p \upharpoonright V_t$ is homeomorphic. $V_t$ is a slice in $p^{-1}(W_t)$.
$\{\tilde{\gamma}^{-1}(V_t) : t \in I\}$ covers $I$, because $I$ is compact, there is a Lebesgue number $\delta$. Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ be sufficiently large that $\frac{1}{N} < \delta$.
Define $I_k := \left[ \frac{k}{N}, \frac{k + 1}{N} \right]$. For each $k \in N$, $\tilde{\gamma}(I_k) \subseteq V_{t_k}$ for some $t_k \in I_k$. $V_k := V_{t_k}$, $W_k := W_{t_k}$.
Define $W := V_0 \times_p \bigcap_{k \in N} S(I_k, W_k)$. $W \in (E \times_p B^I)[(e, \gamma)]$.
Let $(e', \gamma') \in W$. $\gamma'(t) \in W_k$ for $t \in I_k$.
$\tilde{\eta} := \varphi(e', \eta)$. Try to show that $\tilde{\eta}(I) \subseteq U$.
Show $\tilde{\eta}(I_k) \subseteq V_k$.
If $\tilde{\eta}\left( \frac{k}{N} \right) \in V_k$ then $\tilde{\eta}(I_k) \subseteq V_k$ since $\tilde{\eta}(I_k) \subseteq p^{-1}(W_t)$ and is connected.
Show by induction that $\tilde{\eta}\left( \frac{k}{N} \right) \in V_k$
$\tilde{\eta}(0) = e \in V_0$ by the definition of $W$
Suppose $\tilde{\eta}\left( \frac{l}{N} \right) \in V_l$ then $\tilde{\eta}\left( \frac{l + 1}{N} \right) \in \tilde{\eta}(I_l) \subseteq V_l$. $\eta\left( \frac{l + 1}{N} \right) \in W_l \cap W_{l + 1}$, there must be exactly one slice in $p^{-1}(W_{l + 1})$ that intersects with $V_l$, that is exactly $V_{l + 1}$ because $\tilde{\gamma}\left( \frac{l + 1}{N} \right) \in V_l \cap V_{l + 1}$. By the additional conclusion in Lemma 1, $\tilde{\eta}\left( \frac{l + 1}{N} \right) \in V_{l + 1}$.

$\square$
Lemma 1.
Let $p : E \to B$ be a covering map and $U, V \in B[x]$ be two trivializing neighborhoods of $x$. $p^{-1}(U) = \bigsqcup_{f \in F} C_f$ and $p^{-1}(V) = \bigsqcup_{f \in F} D_f$ where $C_f$ and $D_f$ are slices. For each $C_f$, there is exactly one $D_g$ that intersects with $C_f$. And for the unique $y \in C_f$ that $p(y) \in x$, also holds $y \in D_g$.
Proof:
$y := (p \upharpoonright C_f)^{-1}(x) \in C_f$, $p(y) = x$
$y \in p^{-1}(V)$, $y \in D_g$ for some $g$, $y \in C_f \cap D_g$, hence $y \in D_g$
$z \in C_f \cap D_h$, $p(z) \in U \cap V$
$\exists z' \in D_g . p(z') = p(z)$
$z, z' \in C_f$, $(p \upharpoonright C_f)(z) = (p \upharpoonright C_f)(z')$, $z = z'$ for $p \upharpoonright C_f$ is a bijection, $D_g = D_h$ for $\{D_f\}$ are pairwise disjoint
$\square$

Are you only asking about how to finish your proof or also about alternative solutions? Please always include the explicit question you want to ask in your post.

@BenSteffan I've completed my proof, so an alternative would be appreciated.

If you are asking for your proof to be checked, you should keep in mind that on this site a proof checking question which expects the reader to comb through your proof line by line is off topic. Instead, you should edit your post to tell us which step(s) of the proof you are doubtful about, or what other specific concerns you might have about the validity of your proof.

If you know that covering maps are fibrations (the proof of which seems easier than your proof), this is an easy consequence of the exponential law.

If you know that $p$ is a fibration, this is follows from the exponentional law, i.e. a map $f\colon X\to E^I$ is continuous iff the adjoint map $\hat f\colon X\times I\to E, \hat f(x,t)=f(x)(t)$ is continuous. In your case consider the homotopy $h\colon (E\times_p B^I)\times I\to B, h(e,\gamma,t) = \gamma(t)$ and lift it to a homotopy $H\colon (E\times_p B^I)\times I\to E$ with initial condition $H(e,\gamma, 0) = e$. The adjoint map is exactly the path lifting function.
If you don't know that $p$ is a fibration, here is a proof, which can be found in most standard texts.
Lemma: If $\mathcal{U}$ is an open covering of $X\times I$, then for any $x\in X$ there is a neighborhood $V(x)$ of $b$ and $n=n(x)$ such that $V(x)\times [i/n,(i+1)/n]$ is contained in some member of $\mathcal{U}$ for $i=0, \ldots, n-1$.
Proof: Fix $x$. By definition of the product topology there is for each $t\in I$ a neighborhood $V(t)$ of $x$ and a neighborhood $U(t)$ of $t$ such that $V(t)\times U(t)$ is contained in a member of $\mathcal{U}$. The  collection $\{U(t)\}_{t\in I}$ is an open cover of $I$. By the Lebesgue number lemma there is an $n$ such that $i=0,\ldots, n-1$, $[i/n,(i+1)/n]\subset U(t_i)$ for some $t_i$, hence $V(x) = \bigcap_{i=0}^{n-1} V(t_i)$ is the desired neighborhood.
Proof that a covering map is a fibration: First note that the projection $p\colon F\times B\to B$ is trivially a fibration. Let $p\colon E\to B$ be a covering. Then if $U$ is an evenly covered neighborhood, $p^{-1}(U)\to U$ is a fibration. Now let $h\colon X\times I\to B$ be a homotopy with initial condition $f\colon X\to E$. Note that $H$ is unique if it exists, since $I$ is connected. By uniqueness it suffices to find a neighborhood $V(x)$ and a lift $H\colon V(x)\times I\to E$ of $h\vert_{V(x)\times I}$ with initial condition $f\vert_{V(x)}$. By the previous lemma there is for each $x\in X$ a neighborhood $V(x)$ and $n = n(x)$ such that $h(V(x)\times [i/n, (i+1)/n])$ is contained in an evenly covered neighborhood of $B$. Now we can do induction over $i$: Suppose we have a lift $H\colon V(x)\times [0,i/n]\to E$, then we can lift $h\vert_{V(x)\times [i/n,(i+1)/n]}$ with initial condition $H\vert_{V(x)\times \{i/n\}}$ to extend $H$ to $V(x)\times [0,(i+1)/n]$.
